# Confused about ecma/es5, ecma/es6. How do i know what my codebase is?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm a bit confused about the whole "javascript version" in general. How do i know what version is supported by what browser, and how do i know what my framework (in example stenciljs) outputs? How can i check if an existing, minified file is ecma5 or ecma6?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not about language version, it's about language features which comes from ECMAscript specification.

You can check JS features supported by browsers on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/) or kangax's [table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

When it comes about libraries they often write about browser support.

For example, Stencil [does](https://stenciljs.com/docs/browser-support),
React [does](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/)

Also there are tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) which are created for for code transpilation. It means that we can put ES-next code to babel, specify target browsers, for example IE11. And it returns code which is able to run in older environments. But not all features may be transpilated.

Comment: For those who is looking for ecma specification: [link](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-262/)